# Google-Oauth2 not registering new user in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-oauth

When I implemented Google Oauth2 in my Django project,at the backend the user column in python social auths is providing admin mail as user and uid as the email of person who signed in.
Post that no new user is able to sign in.It states Type Error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUrIZ.png)